# is there an easy way to bring a dictionary into a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

The goal is to play craps with this.

I created a dictionary "all_dice" and I end up passing it through 3 functions before it is used.

There must be an easier way to access the dictionary without just passing it over and over again like this.

````
import random
from random import randint

x = 0
the_dice_chosen = ""

##this is the dictionary

all_dice = {"six": 
        [["_____",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["_____",],],
        "five": 
        [["_____",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["  0  ",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["_____",],],
        "four": 
        [["_____",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["     ",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["_____",],],
        "three": 
        [["_____",],
        ["0    ",],
        ["  0  ",],
        ["    0",],
        ["_____",],],
        "two": 
        [["_____",],
        ["0    ",],
        ["    ",],
        ["    0",],
        ["_____",],],
        "one": 
        [["_____",],
        ["     ",],
        ["  0  ",],
        ["     ",],
        ["_____",],],}

## This prints the dictionary of the numbers chosen side by side.
## Again "all_dice" is passed as "ad" and is used.

def dice_print(ndy,ndz,ad):
    x = 0
    nday = ad[ndy]
    ndaz = ad[ndz]
    for i in nday:
        print(nday[x], ndaz[x])
        x = x + 1

##This creates the random dice numbers.       

def dice_roller():
    x = randint(1, 6) 
    y = randint(1, 6) 
    return(x, y)

## This converts the numbers into selections in the dictionary. E.G. 6 into "six" "all_dice" is ad
## and it will from now on be passed as "ad".

def dice_maker(ad,):
    master = {1 : "one",
              2 : "two",
              3 : "three",
              4 : "four",
              5 : "five",
              6 : "six",}
    for i in range(1,2):
        x = dice_roller()
        y = int(x[0])
        z = int(x[1])
        new_die_y = (master[y])
        new_die_z = (master[z])
        dice_print(new_die_y,new_die_z,ad)


##This calls the script to action and passing the dictionary "all_dice"

dice_maker(all_dice)```
````

Comment: Your dictionary is global, you can access it everywhere directly.

Comment: So I was over thinking it all along. SIGH.
Thank you so much. :D

Comment: You might want to check my answer below for some tips on condensing your code. Also, the way you represent the dice in all_dice could be modified more simply by making a die a list of strings rather than a list of lists of strings.

Comment: I was able to rewrite your code into one function with four lines of code by restructuring your all_dice dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can totally discard it as a parameter.

A python module behaves very much like a singleton class. A module, like a class, is an object. `all_dice` is an attribute of the module and hence accessible to the functions scoped to the same module.

```py
import random
from random import randint

x = 0
the_dice_chosen = ""

##this is the dictionary

all_dice = {"six": 
        [["_____",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["_____",],],
        "five": 
        [["_____",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["  0  ",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["_____",],],
        "four": 
        [["_____",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["     ",],
        ["0   0",],
        ["_____",],],
        "three": 
        [["_____",],
        ["0    ",],
        ["  0  ",],
        ["    0",],
        ["_____",],],
        "two": 
        [["_____",],
        ["0    ",],
        ["    ",],
        ["    0",],
        ["_____",],],
        "one": 
        [["_____",],
        ["     ",],
        ["  0  ",],
        ["     ",],
        ["_____",],],}

## This prints the dictionary of the numbers chosen side by side.
## Again "all_dice" is passed as "ad" and is used.

def dice_print(ndy,ndz):
    x = 0
    nday = all_dice[ndy]
    ndaz = all_dice[ndz]
    for i in nday:
        print(nday[x], ndaz[x])
        x = x + 1

##This creates the random dice numbers.       

def dice_roller():
    x = randint(1, 6) 
    y = randint(1, 6) 
    return(x, y)

## This converts the numbers into selections in the dictionary. E.G. 6 into "six" "all_dice" is ad
## and it will from now on be passed as "ad".

def dice_maker():
    master = {1 : "one",
              2 : "two",
              3 : "three",
              4 : "four",
              5 : "five",
              6 : "six",}
    for i in range(1,2):
        x = dice_roller()
        y = int(x[0])
        z = int(x[1])
        new_die_y = (master[y])
        new_die_z = (master[z])
        dice_print(new_die_y,new_die_z)


##This calls the script to action and passing the dictionary "all_dice"

dice_maker()
```

## The `global` keyword

If you require to reassign `all_dice` in a function. You must add `global all_dice` to the function.

```py
all_dice = None

def set_all_dice(value):
    global all_dice
    all_dice = value

def _set_all_dice(value):
    all_dice = value       ## all_dice here is scoped to the function
```

Comment: Um, this isn't how classes work in Python, so this is a misleading statement. So, names in a class scope **are not accessible to methods in that class**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is why I said _singleton_ class. An object of a singleton class has attributes, and those attributes are the same for all object references. The same is true for a module. When you import a module but in a different way, that module has attributes and those attributes are the same for all imports of that module. Yet, in both cases we're talking about object attributes, and from a perspective of the user of such object they behave the same. _Probably singleton class object would be better phrased. I'll let you judge._

Comment: Yes, **but the scope doesn't work the same way**, singletons or not. Again, you stated "all_dice is an attribute of the module and hence accessible to the functions scoped to the same module." But that isn't how class scope works in python.

Comment: There's actually a lot of inefficiency in the code due to the die representation and dictionary keys. I was able to reimplement the code into one function of 4 lines (see below) just by modifying the all_dice dict.

Comment: @Todd That is out of scope of the question as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues not if I declare it global =)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Then how does it work? Please explain.

Comment: I was just trying to be humorous @juanpa.arrivillaga if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: If there is a global variable in a module, let's say `foo` then in a function in a module, I can access `foo` if there is a class attribute `foo` then I **cannot** access it in a method belonging to that class by using `foo`, that is how it is crucially different

Comment: Oh.. you're talking about the distinction between having to use self. to access class members vs. the global keyword in module functions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok ma man. `a  = A()` `a.some_attribute` `import b` `b.some_attribute` the behaviour for attribute access is the same if `class A` is a singleton. That's what I meant. You're talking about implementation differences between both, which is not what I was talking about. We are both right, I'm afraid, in different ways, about different things.

Answer (score 1):

You could condense a lot of that code. The function that prints could be condensed using ''.join() and a list comprehension. And the dice_roller() function being only a couple lines of active code could just be included in the primary function.

```
>>> def roll():
...     num_words = ["dummy", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
...     x = randint(1, 6)
...     y = randint(1, 6)
...     d1 = all_dice[num_words[x]]
...     d2 = all_dice[num_words[y]]
...     roll_str = ''.join(["%s %s\n" % (d1[i][0], d2[i][0]) for i in range(5)])
...     print(roll_str)
>>> roll()
_____ _____
0     0   0
        0  
    0 0   0
_____ _____
```

By reimplementing all_dice like so:

```
all_dice = {6: ["____", "0  0", "0  0", "0  0", "____"], 5: <and so on...>
```

The code is further simplified:

```
>>> def roll():
...     d1 = all_dice[randint(1, 6)]
...     d2 = all_dice[randint(1, 6)]
...     print(''.join(["%s %s\n" % (d1[i], d2[i]) for i in range(5)]))
>>> roll()
_____ _____
0     0   0
        0  
    0 0   0
_____ _____
```